# Android Studio unable to test app without create an apk

Tags: android, testing, apk

I created an apk of my application, and now i don't how to test it in the old version, just connecting my phone and click on play button.
If i click on play button android studio opens a menu, and also ask to me about sign the application.

How i can come back and testing the app in traditional way?

[image]

Comment: You have to make an APK to test. Otherwise how would the code be loaded onto the device? You should be able to run the debugger directly from Android Studio without going to the Run configurations

Comment: before the explicit creation of an apk, when i click play it launched the app in my phone, now it opens that windows, and asking me to sign the apk

Comment: Which Gradle task are you running? `installDebug` shouldn't prompt you to sign

Comment: i solved selecting build variant->debug instead of release

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if in your gradle file you have this :

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
```

or in your AndroidManifest.xml file like this :

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Comment: i don't have it, but also in a previous version i check and i don't have debuggable true

Comment: Can you add it to see ? according the guide [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html)

Comment: nothing...it still open edit configuration windows and asking me to sign an apk i previous created...i want to come back , when i click play it should open just the window where it ask if i want use the device or the simulator